# Bug in Top Questions

Tags: bug, questions, network-profile

I was recently looking at my network profile, and one of my PPCG questions, [Qwerty Quine Creation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78728/qwerty-quine-creation), was listed as `5 votes`. [image: None] However, when I clicked the link, here is the result:

[image: None]

[image: None]

Simple math says that `9 - 3 = 6`, `6 =/= 5`. Don't tell me this is caching, because the question was last upvoted on May 27.

Comment: The network profile is updated every once in a while, not sure how often. The site profiles are accurate. It seems the stats on your network profile hasn't been updated for some time...

Comment: ^ Though that one is referring the top network posts, the problem is still the same, because those posts are derived from the network profile.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Side comment: How can I install the graduation user script?

Comment: @CrazyPython Install TamperMonkey, and click [this](http://rawgit.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design/master/ppcg.user.js).

Comment: @NoOne Wow, this does look cool!

Comment: Where is the page of the features this script provides?

Comment: Ah, I found it.